# Google has retired the QPX Express API

Tags: python, google-qpx-express-api

Now that Google has retired the QPX Express API, is there a different way to pull flight data from their service? I'm hoping to build an app that can send me alerts and data when certain flights and prices change.

Now I know Google flights does something like that already, but I'm wanting to build it my self to practice and add a few extra features to it. I'm working with Python and have a pretty base knowledge so any helpful tips would be great!